# Tesseract can't find word for some odd reason

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I can find other words from other images fine, but it seems like this case seems to prove a challenge for Tesseract.

I can find the word 'Description' accurately in this image:

[image: this image]

but the word 'Desktop' doesn't garner any results even with multiple attempts and blur attempts in between here:

[image: desktopImage]

Here's my code:

```
def OCRscreen(keyword, justCaseCheck):
    # One can just type 'OCRscreen( <WORD YOU'RE LOOKING FOR> )' to find its coordinates
    # If one would like to just see if it's on screen, put "TRUE" after the keyword
    
    # Waiting until the page loads
    numTries = 0        # keeps track of the number of times 
    maxNumTries = 3     # max number of tries
    while True:

        pyautogui.screenshot('imageToOCR.png')     # taking screenshot of desktop

        #have Tesseract read it and convert to GRAY SCALE
        readImage = cv2.imread('imageToOCR.png')        # will pyautogui.screenshot overwrite itself?
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(readImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        thresh = 255 - cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]      # using Otsu's threshold to binarize foreground from background


        #Write GRAY SCALE image to disk as a temp file to OCR it
        tempFile = "{}.png".format(os.getpid() )
        cv2.imwrite(tempFile, thresh) # gray)

        results = pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open(tempFile), lang='eng', config='--psm 6', output_type=Output.DICT)       

        # Checks to see if our keyword showed up on screen
        if keyword not in results["text"]:
            print("Attempted without blur. Now trying a blurred image... ")

            # Try blurring this time
            blurredImage = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3,3), 0)     # blur before processing
            tempFile_blur = "{}.png".format(os.getpid() )
            cv2.imwrite(tempFile_blur, blurredImage)
            results = pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open(tempFile), lang='eng', config='--psm 6', output_type=Output.DICT)

            if keyword not in results["text"]:
                numTries += 1
                print(f"Identifier '{keyword}' was not found. Trying again. This is attempt {numTries}. After {maxNumTries} attempts the script will stop. ")
                time.sleep(0.5)

            if numTries == maxNumTries:
                print(f"We have reached {maxNumTries} attempts. ")

                if justCaseCheck == True:
                    return      # would return None if it's not found. 
                                    # If we DID find it, then it would return the coordinates
                elif justCaseCheck == False:
                    input("We are either not on the correct page, or OCR has failed to find our keyword. Script will now exit. ")
                    exit()

        elif keyword in results["text"]:
            break
                        
    keywordToString = str(keyword) # changing keyword to String
    # Checking for the keyword in the results BEFORE WE MOVE ON
    if keywordToString not in results["text"]:
        print("Didn't find keyword on screen. Please check that the appropriate SAP page is open on the screen. " )
        input('Press ENTER to exit now. ')
        exit()
    
    return center_x, center_y
```

Could anyone please give some insight on why this might be happening, and how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I re-read what PSM does for PyTesseract and found that I had misinterpreted it before. From what I understand, it seems like --psm 6 means that it's looking for blocks of text like you would a paragraph. I switched it to --psm 11 which just looks for sparse text which is more applicable in this case.